# Create a .png with zopfli

Tags: browser, compression, png

I wanted to give zopfli a try since I have some static .png's that I am using on a website.

I see how I can create .gz and .deflate-files. But how can I create a png that can be displayed in FF, Chrome and Co?

```
zopfli --i1000 _385.png
```

The resulting .gz-file is about 4% smaller then the one created with pngCrush (which was about 2% smaller then the original).

Answer (score 7):

**Zopfli** cannot handle PNG directly.

But you can use [ehoeks-zopfli-png](https://code.google.com/r/ehoeks-zopfli-png/):

```
zopfli --png --i1000 logo.png
```

You will have to compile it:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/r/ehoeks-zopfli-png
cd ehoeks-zopfli-png/
make
./zopfli --png --i1000 logo.png
```

Note that this will only re-compress using the DEFLATE algorithm, you should optimize it first using other tools (**OptiPNG**, **pngout**, etc...) and other techniques (a bit off topic here, but check pngquant for smart lossy compression of PNG)

After compressing, you can still optimize it further using tools such as **DeflOpt** and **defluff**, but as far as I know this will only save a few bytes.

Another solution, windows-only, is [PNGZopli](http://x128.ho.ua/pngutils.html), included in [ScriptPNG](http://css-ig.net/scriptpng) alongside other tools. And there's also [optipng-zopfli](https://github.com/sayurin/optipng-zopfli) (optipng plus zopfli) but I haven't tried it yet.

**Update**: PNG support is [being added](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/source/browse/README.zopflipng) in zopfli

Answer (score 3):

While you're waiting for tools to integrate it, there is zopfli support in the [advancecomp project](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/comp-readme.html), which is available in ubuntu and homebrew repos. It provides various compression tools that are independent of its MAME project origins, but the main one of interest is `advdef` which can recompress the compressed regions of PNG files. An effective workflow is to pass your images through a PNG optimiser such as optipng (to deal with PNG-specific aspects), then through advdef, for example:

`optipng -quiet -o2 -nb mypic.png && advdef -z -4 mypic.png`

the `-4` option tells it to use 'insane' compression levels, i.e. zopfli. The project also includes `advpng`, but it's not as good as optipng so you're better off using advdef by itself.

A pretty exhaustive comparison of PNG optimisers and recompressors can be found [here](http://css-ig.net/png-tools-overview). It's a shame that TruePNG is Windows only and not open source.